# How to makes the size of the text change on different sized screens android programming

Tags: android, xml, text, size

I am currently making an android app that involves the use of a lot of buttons. When I ran this app on my 7 inch android galaxy tab 2 the size of the text was about right. When however I ran the application on the emulator that I made on my computer which is much smaller the text was much bigger which meant that many of my buttons did not fit on the screen. I have tried using "sp" and "dp" rather than "px" however the text is still different sizes. Is their anything that I can do so that the size of the text will adapt to the size of the screen?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: No, you shouldn't have to do this either.  Devices and users determine their own font sizes.  You should rework your layout if small differences in font size affect it so much.

Comment: @ashishduh, is correct. You should define separate layouts for various screen sizes eg using the ldpi, mdpi, hdpi, xhdpi suffixes in your resources folders. Read through [the official tutorial](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) to get started. Because of the variety of devices that run Android there is no "one size fits all" solution.

Comment: @indivisible is correct too. :) But I should add: do _not_ use `px` for fonts. Pixels have very different physical sizes in different screens. Use `sp` (or in some cases `dp`) instead.

Comment: Thank you very much for all your help I have now sorted out the problem.